# Lagrangean uniqueness versus Eulerian uniqueness

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

(1) Lagrangean description. Let us consider a $N\times N$ system of autonomous ODE:
$$
\dot x=a(x),\quad \mathbb R\ni t\mapsto x(t)\in \mathbb R^N,\quad a:\mathbb R^N\rightarrow \mathbb R^N.
$$
Instead of assuming the traditional Cauchy-Lipschitz hypothesis, let me suppose
$$
\vert a(x_1)-a(x_2)\vert\le \omega(\vert x_1-x_2\vert)
$$
where $\omega:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow(0,+\infty)$ continuous increasing, $\omega(0_+)=0$
such that the so-called Osgood condition holds:
$$
\exists R>0,\quad\text{such that}\quad \int_0^R\frac{dr}{\omega(r)}=+\infty.\tag{Osgood}
$$
It is of course satisfied by $\omega(r)=r$ (Lipschitz case) but also by
$\omega(r)=r\log(1/r)$ or $r\log(1/r)r\log\log(1/r)$.
Existence and uniqueness are not difficult to prove and follow from a Gronwall-type argument.
The flow has some regularity properties, is not Lipschitz-continuous in general, but is better than Hölder of any index $<1$.

(2) Eulerian description. We consider the PDE, in fact the autonomous vector field
$$
X=\sum_{1\le j\le N}a_j(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}
$$
where $a=(a_1,\dots,a_N)$ satisfies the above Osgood assumption.
MY QUESTION:
How can we prove uniqueness of $L^\infty$ weak solutions $u$ to the IVP
$$
Xu=f,\quad u_{\vert \Sigma}=0,\quad \text{$\Sigma$ is a $C^1$ hypersurface transverse to $X$}?
$$

(3) Comment: DiPerna-Lions theory does not apply since derivatives of the function $a$ could even fail to be a measure and may be a distribution of positive order. If you don't like autonomous vector fields, you can formulate the question for
$$
X=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\sum_{1\le j\le N}a_j(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j},\quad
\Sigma\equiv t=0,\quad
\vert a_j(t,x)-a_j(t,y)\vert\le C\omega(\vert x-y\vert).
$$

Comment: The uniqueness of the PDE in $L^\infty$ would follow from the solvability backwards of the dual equation in $L^1$. From the solvability of the ODE you can solve the dual equation in the space of measures by pulling back the flow. What I don't quite see is how to show that these measures would stay absolutely continuous so that they are an $L^1$ function. The problem is equivalent to understanding whether the flow of the ODE maps sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero. I don't know if that is true but I think it is equivalent to your question.

This paper is related http://arxiv.org/abs

Comment: Sorry, I meant this paper is related, but does not solve your question.
Ambrosio, Luigi(I-SNS); Bernard, Patrick(F-PARIS9-A)
Uniqueness of signed measures solving the continuity equation for Osgood vector fields.
Atti Accad. Naz. Lincei Cl. Sci. Fis. Mat. Natur. Rend. Lincei Mat. Appl. 19 (2008), no. 3, 237–245.


Comment: @Luis Silvestre
Thanks for your remarks. I certainly agree with the fact that the quoted paper by Ambrosio \& Bernard does not solve my question. The problem seems to come from the definition of the product of a measure by a measurable function, always possible in measure theory, but not in distribution theory. In particular, the definition of a weak solution for a PDE is indeed using distribution theory, with a formal integration by parts.